# Using Joins in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables:

```
class Candidate(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'candidates'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String)
    first = Column(String)
    last = Column(String)
    company = Column(String)
    title = Column(String)
    linkedin_url = Column(String, unique=True)
    role = Column(String)

    emails = relationship("Email", back_populates="candidate")

class Email(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'emails'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    candidate_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('candidates.id'))
    email_id = Column(String, nullable=False)
    thread_id = Column(String, nullable=False)
    date = Column(String, nullable=False)
    subject = Column(String, nullable=False)
    to = Column(String, nullable=False)
    carbon_copy = Column(String, nullable=False)
    from_ =  Column(String, nullable=False)
    text_body = Column(String, nullable=False)
    epoch_time = Column(String, nullable=False)

    candidate = relationship("Candidate", back_populates="emails")
```

I'm trying to write a join in SQLAlchemy:

```
q = db_session.query(Candidate).join(Email)
```

I'd like to be able to do something like `q.first().email_id` and `q.first().id` but I'm getting an error `AttributeError: 'Candidate' object has no attribute 'email_id'`

When I print out the raw SQL: `print str(q)` it returns `FROM candidates JOIN emails ON candidates.id = emails.candidate_id`

which looks correct.

So why do I get an error when I try to access the joined table? `q.first().id` returns `1` but `q.first().email_id` gives an error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: can a Candidate have many Email objects attached to it? It's confusing that Candidate has an `email` property, but then also has an `emails` property that references any linked Candidate objects.

Comment: `email` is their email address and emails is the foreign key to the Email class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`q = db_session.query(Candidate, Email).join(Email)`

That expression does what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem. Since you have a one-to-many relationship between Candidate and Email (meaning one candidate can have many emails), when you access your candidate's `emails` property you are actually accessing a list.

so instead of

```
q.first().email_id
```

you would need to use

```
for each in q.first().emails:
    print each.email_id
```

Comment: I guess I was hoping to return a table that has a row for every email. IE - `ID` | `Email` | ... | `candidate_id` | `email_id` | for every

Comment: in that case you don't want to query a Candidate, but an Email instead. Reverse your query. Right now you will only return a list of candidates which each have their own `emails` property.

Comment: instead of `q = db_session.query(Candidate).join(Email)` use `q = db_session.query(Email).join(Candidate)`

Comment: then I have the problem of accessing Candidate columns. From my understanding of joins, is that it will create a table in memory that has the columns from both tables, and it shouldn't matter the order of the join

Comment: This may go beyond my expertise then. I believe the table in memory doesn't last longer than the query itself. Once that table is created it is your job then to tell sqlalchemy what you want to extract from it and then the temp table is gone.

Comment: I'm storing the table to the variable `q`, but I don't get why not all of the columns are being joined in `q`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280862/sqlalchemy-getting-a-single-object-from-joining-multiple-tables - try this