# Flask-SQLAlchemy: How to return a list of single objects after performing a join operation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables Users and Organization.

I have the following SQL mapped classes:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column('first_name', db.String)
    second_name = db.Column('second_name', db.String)
    last_name = db.Column('last_name', db.String)
    # organization_id = db.Column('organization_id', db.Integer)
    organization_id = db.Column('organization_id',db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('organization.id'),nullable=False)
    # organization = db.relationship('Organization',backref='user',lazy=False)
    email = db.Column('email', db.String)
    mobile_no = db.Column('mobile_no', db.String)
    designation = db.Column('designation', db.String)
    role_id = db.Column('role_id', db.Integer)
    password = db.Column('password', db.String)

class Organization(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'organization'
    id = db.Column('id',db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column('name',db.String)
    type_id = db.Column('type_id',db.Integer)
    ward_id = db.Column('ward_id',db.Integer)
    attrs = ['id','name','type_id','ward_id']
    user_organization = db.relationship('User',backref='organization',lazy=False)
```

I want to perform a join operation on User.onrganization_id and Organization.id with the results looking like this

user.id | user.first_name  organization.name | user.email | user.mobile_no

I tried this code:

```
q = db.session.query(User,Organization).join(Organization).all()
```

This give me a result as list with collection of object:

```
[(<User 2>, <Organization 1>)]
```

I want the return type to be a list of single object and not a collection of objects. Like this

```
[(<UsersAndOrganization1>)] //Name of the object doesn't have to be the same
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `lazy=False` on your relationship, SQLAlchemy will perform the join automatically when you do `User.query.all()`.  In the query results each user will have `organization` property populated, so you will be able to access its fields as, for example, `user.organization.name`.

Regardless of the `lazy` option in the relationship configuration, you can always achieve the same effect by explicitly specifying load options in the query:

```
users = User.query.options(db.joinedload(Organization)).all()
```

More info can be found in the docs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#joined-eager-loading) (`lazy=False` is synonym to `lazy='joined'`).

Also, try enabling `SQLALCHEMY_ECHO` in your Flask app config and see the actual SQL queries emitted by SQLAlchemy.  It is always very useful to see what happens under the hood.

Comment: That worked, thanks but I am trying to access the organization name through a single object and not object within a object. I need to access the organization name through some like this "user.name". Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need them in one object? With your configuration the whole organization row is fetched from database anyway.

Comment: An option would be to add a `@property` on the User class returning `self.organization.name`

Comment: For anyone still looking for an answer to get one object I put an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60883545/3620725